# iOS 13 Fullscreen UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios13, uimodalpresentationstyle

I'm updating an app for iOS 13 support and one of the requirements (for now) is to convert all of the modal `UIViewControllers` back to `UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen`, but the `UIImagePickerController` does not seem to respect the value I'm passing it and is always in "Card View" when I'm picking photos and in fullScreen when I'm picking videos.

Is there a way to make both ViewControllers have the same appearance, either as cards or fullscreen?

Comment: Thank you @matt for the clarification.

Comment: I rarely disagree with @matt, so maybe I'm misunderstanding the question. I just tested things and when `sourceType = .photoLibrary` and `modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` the picker is limited to photos and is presented full screen in iOs 13. what am I missing?

Comment: @dfd Hmmm. In my project, `sourceType = .photoLibrary` and `modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` and I still get the card apperance, so maybe I'm the one who's missing something. I'll check it again and get back at you.

Comment: I was experiencing the same issue with UIImagePickerViewController until I realized that setting `picker.presentationController?.delegate` to a value would cause the modal presentation style setting to be ignored. It worked as expected when I didn't set that delegate property.

Answer (score 1):

Not looking at this as an answer, just help. Here's my working code written in Xcode 11.2 targeting iOS 13.0:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var btnOpenImage = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        btnOpenImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        btnOpenImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        btnOpenImage.setTitle("Show Picker", for: .normal)
        btnOpenImage.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showImagePicker), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(btnOpenImage)

        btnOpenImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180).isActive = true
        btnOpenImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        btnOpenImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        btnOpenImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    @objc func showImagePicker() {
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(imagePicker,
                animated: true,
                completion: nil)
    }
    @objc internal func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

It doesn't do much, but it *does* show things full screen. It was pulled from a much larger project and tested on an iPad Mini running 13.1, and another running 13.2. Also tested in the iPhone 11 Pro simulator.

One thing, while I added the `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` key to `info.plist`, it *never* actually popped anything up!?!